# how to retrieve the details of the student whose name starts with S

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to retireve the detail of students whose names starts with 's'
tablename ---student
columnname---sname
plz tell me the query

Thanks,

Comment: Are these homework questions?

Comment: @Martin, if he is, aren't you tempted to lead him astray?

Comment: Something like `WHERE ABS(ASCII(RIGHT(REVERSE(sname),1))-99) = 16`?

Comment: @Martin – Wouldn't that be unsargable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT sname 
FROM student
WHERE sname LIKE 'S%'
```

Comment: if you are going to use an upper-case 'S' in your `LIKE` expression it might be wise to add `UPPER(sname)`

Comment: @Dan - The `UPPER` makes it unsargable. I suppose to be accurate to the question I should have used `s` but names tend to start with capitals. Depends on the column collation as well whether this makes any difference...

Comment: @Martin, I had to look that one up but yes you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess `WHERE [sname] LIKE 'S%' OR [sname] like 's%'` would be better, right?

Comment: @Dan on a `CS` collation you could also use `LIKE '[Ss]%'`. I must admit I've never investigated whether that would be less efficient than splitting it out into the 2 cases explicitly.

Comment: @Churchill, Since this is basic SQl and you are asking it it appears to be homework. So please explain to us why this works. You didn't think you could get your homework done for free did you? You need to understand why not just what or you will fail as a programmer when you have to do real work.

Comment: this statements returns the person details whose name starts with letter 'S'...plz tell me the website from where i could get  the queries and practice to learn the sql commands